# Graph not displaying data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I'm kinda new to React and I was trying to make a graph using Recharts, but I lost myself in a problem where the lines of the graph doesnt appear.

I use this code

```
const [ graphData, setgraphData ] = useState([])

const createMockData = () => {
let data = [];
let value = 50;
for (var i = 0; i <= 5 ; i++){
  let date = new Date();
  date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  date.setDate(i);
  value += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 0) * Math.random() * 10);
  data.push({x: date, y: value});
} 
//console.log(data);
setgraphData(data);


}
useEffect(() => {
   createMockData();
});
```

To create a mockup data and this to present it

```
<LineChart width={500} height={200} data={graphData}>
    <Line type="monotone" dataKey={graphData.x} stroke="var(--mainColor)" />
    <XAxis dataKey={graphData.y} />
    <Tooltip />
</LineChart>
```

And I dont know what I'm doing wrong. When I use a normal array it works fine, but I need the graph to be like 100 values.

[Sandbox Link](https://w1kruy.csb.app/)

Thank you

Comment: could you share a code-sandbox link with the example

Comment: Try this link https://w1kruy.csb.app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four issues here:

1. You are setting `graphData.x` and `graphData.y` as keys, however these values will be `undefined`. `graphData` is an array and doesn't have `x` or `y` properties - and it wouldn't even make sense, because you are supposed to specify the property names to be used for each object, i.e. `"x"` and `"y"`. You can see in your working graph that you had data objects with `{ Time, Value }`, so the keys specified are `"Time"` and `"Value"`, and now you have `{ x, y }`, so they should be `"x"` and `"y"`.
2. You have `x` and `y` reversed - you are attempting to set `x` as key for the `Line` and `y` as key for the `XAxis`, but it needs to be the other way round.
3. You have `Date` objects in your data, which happen to "work" in the X axis because they are implicitly converted to a string, but the output will not be very readable, and it's not really a supported way of providing X axis values. It would be better to set `x: date.toLocaleDateString()` instead of just `x: date` in your data objects.
4. Your mock data will currently be recreated in a tight loop ad infinitum, eating one CPU core in the process, because you put `createMockData` into `useEffect` but without specifying an empty dependencies array, so any rerender - including the one you trigger yourself inside of `createMockData` will create new mock data, which will cause new mock data to be created, and so on. The solution is to add an empty dependency array to specify that there are no circumstances under which the hook should run a second time.

Working sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-swirles-2vpfl6?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Thank you for the help! It works flawlessly, and thank you aswell for the deep explanation! 

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you should fix to make to make it work:

1. your `useEffect` should have an empty dependency array to prevent the endless re-rendering
2. `dataKey={graphData.x}` should be replaced with `dataKey="x"` and `dataKey={graphData.y}` should be replaced with `dataKey="y"`

Have a look at [the sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/laughing-phoebe-3jstnt) to see the working example

Comment: Thank you for helping me, now I understand what I did wrong